# Odd Matplotlib errors/warnings when producing multiple plots

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

I've got two simulations, each of which produces some data I'd like to plot. What I'm getting are some very strange errors cropping up when I added the 2nd plot. At the moment, my code looks like this:

```
Do Some Simulation

kappa_density = stats.kde.gaussian_kde(kappa_estimate)

x = numpy.arange(0,0.0005,0.00001) 
high_density =max(kappa_density(x)) 
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.plot(x,kappa_density(x)) 
plt.plot((kappa_central, kappa_central),(0,high_density), 'r--') 
a = plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 0.25, 0.25,fc="red", alpha=1.00) 
b = plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 0.25, 0.25,fc="blue",alpha=1.00) 
plt.legend([a,b], ["Median","Density Estimate"],loc=1,fontsize='small') 
plt.xlabel("Kappa",fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel("Density",fontsize=16)
plt.savefig('KappaEstimateDistribution.pdf')

Do some more simulation

fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6)) 
plt.hist(tau_estimate,facecolor='green', alpha=0.5)
plt.savefig('TauEstimateDistribution.pdf')
```

When this runs, the first plot appears as a black, unfilled box on my display, though it's saved correctly as a file. The second bout of simulation completes, is properly saved as a file...and then the program crashes, spitting out a remarkable array of warnings and errors:

```
May 16 18:22:55  python[58033] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const: conn 0x4507f token 0x1ffffffffffe85
May 16 18:22:55  python[58033] <Warning>: Backtrace (at 748802):
May 16 18:22:55  python[58033] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  0   CoreGraphics                        0x00007fff8bd16b98 CGSDisableUpdateToken + 155
May 16 18:22:55  python[58033] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  1   AppKit                              0x00007fff98884524 ___disable_updates_sync_block_invoke_2 + 17
May 16 18:22:55  python[58033] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  2   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8e69740b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
May 16 18:22:55  python[58033] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8e6989f2 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 74
May 16 18:22:55  python[58033] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  4   AppKit                              0x00007fff988843f2 NSCGSDisableUpdates + 213
May 16 18:22:55  python[58033] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  5   AppKit                              0x00007fff98884228 NSCGSTransactionRunPreCommitActionsForOrder_ + 156
May 16 18:22:55  python[58033] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  6   AppKit                              0x00007fff98884179 NSCGSTransactionRunPreCommitActions_ + 31
May 16 18:22:55  python[58033] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  7   AppKit                              0x00007fff988661e3 -[_NSCGSTransaction addActionWithOrder:usingBlock:] + 220
May 16 18:22:55  python[58033] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  8   AppKit                              0x00007fff988660f7 NSCGSTransactionAddAction + 68
May 16 18:22:55  python[58033] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  9   AppKit                              0x00007fff988659f9 NSCGSWindowBackingStoreMark_ + 257
May 16 18:22:55  python[58033] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  10  AppKit                              0x00007fff988658ed -[_NSCGSWindowBackingStore setAttached:] + 57
May 16 18:22:55  python[58033] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  11  AppKit                              0x00007fff9893bd75 _NSCreateWindowWithOpaqueShape2 + 150
May 16 18:22:55  python[58033] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  12  AppKit                              0x00007fff9893a980 -[NSWindow _commonAwake] + 1960
May 16 18:22:55  python[58033] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  13  AppKit                              0x00007fff9893a166 -[NSWindow _makeKeyRegardlessOfVisibility] + 85
May 16 18:22:55  python[58033] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  14  AppKit                              0x00007fff98873429 NSPerformVisuallyAtomicChange + 147
May 16 18:22:55  python[58033] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  15  AppKit                              0x00007fff9893a0af -[NSWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:] + 79
May 16 18:22:55  python[58033] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  16  _macosx.so                          0x000000010b4ad22d FigureManager_show + 77
May 16 18:22:55  python[58033] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  17  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x00000001000c5385 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 31621
May 16 18:22:55  python[58033] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  18  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x00000001000c83a3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131
May 16 18:22:55  python[58033] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  19  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x000000010003e100 function_call + 176
May 16 18:22:55  python[58033] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  20  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x000000010000c552 PyObject_Call + 98
May 16 18:22:55  python[58033] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  21  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x000000010001dbed instancemethod_call + 333
May 16 18:22:55  python[58033] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  22  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x000000010000c552 PyObject_Call + 98
May 16 18:22:55  python[58033] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  23  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x00000001000792d8 slot_tp_init + 88
May 16 18:22:55  python[58033] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  24  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x0000000100076155 type_call + 245
May 16 18:22:55  python[58033] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  25  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x000000010000c552 PyObject_Call + 98
May 16 18:22:55  python[58033] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  26  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x00000001000c0013 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10259
May 16 18:22:55  python[58033] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  27  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x00000001000c83a3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131
May 16 18:22:55  python[58033] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  28  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x00000001000c567d PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 32381
May 16 18:22:55  python[58033] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  29  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x00000001000c83a3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131
May 16 18:22:55  python[58033] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  30  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x000000010003e100 function_call + 176
May 16 18:22:55  python[58033] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  31  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x000000010000c552 PyObject_Call + 98
```

This is irritating, rather than catastrophic, because it crashes once it's finished with everything, but it's still an odd error. Can anyone see what I'm doing to trigger this?